# Remove a div with the same class as another div

Tags: jquery

I have two divs:

```
<div class="dialog large"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="dialog"></div>
```

I have to remove the one with the class "dialog" but keep the one with "dialog large".

If I do `$('dialog').remove();` they are both removed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div.dialog:not(.large)').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/512/)**

#### A little explain

`div.dialog` will select `div` with `class=dialog` (in this case both div will select). But

`div.dialog:not(.large)` will exclude those `div` with `class` `large` and remove them.

#### Related Refs

- **[:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**
- **[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("div.dialog").not('.large').remove();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v74V4/1/) here...

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do it. You could also use `filter()` as an alternative maybe suitable for other more complicated cases.

```
$('div.dialog').filter(function(){ return !$(this).is('.large') })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove DIVs where the class is exactly "dialog", try:

```
$('div[class="dialog"]').remove();
```

Comment: What if there were elements that had the `dialog` class and some other class, but not the `large` class?

Comment: `div[class="dialog"]` will match DIVs that have only the `dialog` class and none others.  `[attr=value]` is an exact match, as opposed to `[attr*=value]`, which would match all DIVs that include `dialog`, but not exclusively.

Comment: I know, my point was that this won't work for what the OP is trying to do in the situation that a `div` has the class name `dialog` and something else other than `large`.